# Get max date for user from another table

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, in one table I am storing user statuses and in the second logs.

"status" table

```
 id , customerId, userName, serviceId, status
```

"logs" table

```
id, customerId, logDate, status
```

I need to get the latest log for each customer for specific date intervals (from 2020-10-01 to 2020-11-31)  and specific status (status = 6). All customer logs are stored in the "logs" table.

This is what I tried but no luck:

```
Select distinct (a.customerId),  a.userName, a.serviceId, a.status, max(logDate)
FROM status a 
JOIN logs b 
WHERE logDate BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-11-31' and a.customerId = b.customerId and a.status = 6 group by b.logDate
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results would help.  (3) `DISTINCT` is *not* a function.  Parentheses are not warranted.  Of particular interest is whether `customerId` is repeated in the `status` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `group by` clause is off: you would need to group by all non-aggregated columns.

```
select s.customerid, s.username, s.serviceid, s.status, max(l.logdate) as maxlogdate
from status s
inner join logs l
where 
    l.logdate >= '2020-10-01' 
    and l.logdate < '2020-12-01' 
    and l.customerid = s.customerid 
    and s.status = 6 
group by s.customerid, s.username, s.serviceid, s.status
```

Some databases support just putting the primary key of the `status` table in the `group by` clause. Assuming that it is `customerid`:

```
group by s.customerid
```

Note that I changed the query to use *meaningful* table aliases.